# content script is not able to access chrome.tabs.* even after adding external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, google-chrome-extension

I want a my plugin to work on load of any page and change some content of it, for that i have written content script, and added external js file, in external js file I am not able to access chrome.tab.*  am I doing wrong?

------ content script ----

```
debugger;
var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
            (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
            s.parentNode.removeChild(s);


            /*chrome.runtime.sendMessage('3645374', 'any message',[] , function(){  alert('---...---'); } )     ;   

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "doWhatYouWant();"});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
            (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
            s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"doWhatYouWant();"});
        }
    });
});*/
```

--------------------  script.js --------------

```
function doWhatYouWant(){
    alert('inside .... doWhatYouWant');
    document.getElementById('zx12').value = "CHANGED !";
}


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    debugger;
        alert('I am here too ');
        // Execute some script when the page is fully (DOM) ready
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code:"doWhatYouWant();"});
    }
});


/*chrome.extensions.onRequest.addLiestener( function(p1,p2,p3){
  alert('done');
  document.getElementById('zx12').value = "CHANGED !";
});



chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (){
   alert('doWhatYouWant called');
});



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('zx12').value = "CHANGED !";
});
*/
```

----------------------- manifest.json ---------------

```
{
  "name": "My Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","contentscript.js"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources" : ["script.js"],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Content scripts cannot use most Chrome extension APIs. (The `chrome.extension.getURL` call you're making is a rare exception.) You will probably need to implement the `chrome.tabs` event listener in a background page in the extension and pass messages to the content script.

Please read [the Google Chrome documentation on content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), especially the introductory section on limitations and the section on the execution environment.